# How to modify the value of $request in Nginx?

Tags: ruby, nginx, chef-infra, erb, chef-recipe

In Nginx, currently we are logging $request. But we want to change value for one request param in it.
We need to log hashed id instead of actual id.
Could you please tell me how can I achieve that ?

**Current value of $request :**

```
POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&name=John&address=UK
```

**Expected value:**

```
POST /test/userRegistration?id=8c77ec99436a23d2c05a6bd36c64de856&name=John&address=UK
```

**Nginx Log Format :**

```
log_format  main '$request $status $request_time';
```

I have written follwoing ruby code to meet my requirement. But I am not sure  how to integrate it in ERB file. That log_format is declared in 
a ERB file.

Code:

```
str = "POST /test/userRegistration?name=John&id=1234&address=UK"
str1 = str.scan(/&id=.+&/)[0]
str1 = str1.chomp('&')
str1 = str1.split("=").last
str1 = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest str1
str2 = "&id="+str1+"&"
str3 = str.sub(/&name=.+&/, str2)
puts str3
```

Please help me writing similar logic in ERB file. Also, please let me know if there is any better way to handle it as I am new to Ruby.

Thanks

Comment: basically you need to override nginx log data only and the idea is to replace id with hashed id?

Comment: @gskillz Thats correct

Answer (score 0):

To me you need to check [openresty](http://openresty.org/en/) project or install LUA extension for Nginx. Its ok to replace nginx with openresty to get LUA out of the box.

With LUA script you can parse this certain part of the request - similar to your ruby code and record modified request uri in Nginx access log.

Here are some examples how you can modify request parameters with [LUA](http://ywebdev.com/?p=1)